xdebug will not work when using visual studio code and lando
I installed lando with a wordpress recipe. The setup works and I am unable to get the code to stop on breakpoints with xdebug. After using the code on the Lando site for toggling on and off xdebug I was able to verify that php is running with xdebug enabled.
Some additional behavior I noticed was that running the command from the launch config the debug screen says it is watching on the defined port. Also, the call stack tab doesn't display anything unless I run the default xdebug configuration command. Then both display as "running" in the call stack tab.
I have my launch.json created and have believe that is where the problem may lie. I have tried changing the pathMappings path in the launch.json to no avail. It also may be that I am missing a crucial point of running lando with xdebug as it spins up a docker container. I didn't adjust any other setting in docker or lando to troubleshoot yet.
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

      {
        "name": "2Listen for XDebug 2",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "pathMappings": {
          "/app/wordpress/": "${workspaceFolder}/",
          
        }
      }
    ]
  }

.lando.yml
name: my-first-wordpress-app
recipe: wordpress
config:
  webroot: wordpress
services:
  myservice:
    type: phpmyadmin
  appserver:
    overrides:
      environment:
        XDEBUG_MODE: 'debug,develop'

tooling:
  xdebug-on:
    service: appserver
    description: Enable Xdebug.
    user: root
    cmd:
      - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && kill -USR2 $(pgrep -o php-fpm) > /dev/null || /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
      - tput setaf 2 && echo "Xdebug On" && tput sgr 0 && echo

  xdebug-off:
    service: appserver
    description: Disable Xdebug.
    user: root
    cmd:
      - rm /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && kill -USR2 $(pgrep -o php-fpm) > /dev/null || /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
      - tput setaf 1 && echo "Xdebug Off" && tput sgr 0 && echo

